# Swift: Get an array of element from an array of tuples

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, tuples

I have an array of tuples like this :

```
var answers: [(number: Int, good: Bool)]
```

I want to get from it an array of number member. Like if I did something like :

```
answers["number"] // -> Should give [Int] of all values named "number"
```

I didn't find anything like it, maybe it's not possible, but it would be sad :(

Answer (score 34, accepted):

That's simple:

```
answers.map { $0.number }
```

Comment: What about mapping all numbers into a single array in this data structure [(numbers:[Int], good: Bool)]

Answer (score 10):

```
var ints = answers.map { tuple in
    tuple.0
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your tuple is not named you can do this:

```
let mappedInts = answers.map({$0.0})
let mappedBools = answers.map({$0.1})
```

Comment: you can alway get a value of a tuple by index - named or not