# Swift: Get an element from a tuple

Tags: swift, tuples

If I have a tuple like this

```
var answer: (number: Int, good: Bool)
```

How do I get one of the elements?

This doesn't work:

```
answer["number"]
```

I am modeling this question after [Swift: Get an array of element from an array of tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26536538/swift-get-an-array-of-element-from-an-array-of-tuples), but my question was a little more basic. I did find the answer buried in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html) so I am adding my answer below in Q&A format for faster searching in the future.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html) (scroll down to Tuples), there are three ways to do it.

Given

```
var answer: (number: Int, good: Bool) = (100, true)
```

**Method 1**

Put the element variable name within a tuple.

```
let (firstElement, _) = answer
let (_, secondElement) = answer
```

or

```
let (firstElement, secondElement) = answer
```

**Method 2**

Use the index.

```
let firstElement = answer.0
let secondElement = answer.1
```

**Method 3**

Use the names. This only works, of course, if the elements were named in the Tuple declaration.

```
let firstElement = answer.number
let secondElement = answer.good
```

Comment: after learning how to declare variables in Swift I have to say that Method 1 really hurts my eyes

Answer (score 1):

I tried this. It's not so good but works...

```
protocol SubscriptTuple {
    associatedtype Tuple
    associatedtype Return
    var value: Tuple { get set }
    subscript(sub: String) -> Return? { get }
}

struct TupleContainer: SubscriptTuple {
    typealias Tuple = (number: Int, good: Bool)
    typealias Return = Any
    var value: Tuple
    subscript(sub: String) -> Return? {
        switch sub {
        case "number":
            return value.number
        case "good":
            return value.good
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how to use.

```
let answer = Answer(value: (120, false))
answer["number"]
```