# Swift - Select a specific value within an array of multiple key/values

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array called `[images]`. Within this array, there is the ID of each image, and the URL of each image. I wish to put only the URL (not the ID) of the selected image into a variable to be used elsewhere.

For example, when I print my entire array:

```
print(images)
```

I get the following:

```
[(id: "nni", URL: "https://bbc.com/a1.jpg"), (id: "9hr", URL: "https://bbc.com/a2.jpg")]
```

I am able to successfully isolate the selected image using the following

```
print(images[indexPath.row)
```

So, if I click on the first image, this print statement will return:

```
[(id: "nni", URL: "https://bbc.com/a1.jpg")] // This is correct
```

However, I ONLY want to isolate that URL, and put it into a new variable, selectedURL

```
selectedURL = "https://bbc.com/a1.jpg"
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift: Get an element from a tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37200162/swift-get-an-element-from-a-tuple)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have an array of tuples (not the best choice).

Do:

```
let selectedURL = images[indexPath.row].URL
```

or:

```
let selectedURL = images[indexPath.row].1
```

But consider creating a struct with id and URL fields.

Comment: Thanks - what makes the struct a better choice?

Comment: A struct is clear. It can have initializers and methods. It's easier to pass around.